# How to compare in C code LONG data from registry?

Tags: c

I think it's easy question who knows C, (i'm not)

I have code that checks if Proxy is enabled.

From Registry:

[image]

From `cmd`:

> C:\Users\Max>reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Cur
>   rentVersion\Internet Settings" | find /i "proxyenable"
>       ProxyEnable    REG_DWORD    0x1

Here is relevant snippets of code:

```
#define POLICY_KEY TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings")

  ...

    HKEY hKey;
LONG lResult;
LONG lResultServer;
DWORD dwValue, dwType, dwSize = sizeof(dwValue);

DWORD szType = REG_SZ;
char rgValue [1024];
DWORD BufSize = sizeof(rgValue);

const char *defaultVal = "0";


lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, POLICY_KEY, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    lResult = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "ProxyEnable", 0, &dwType, (LPBYTE)&dwValue, &dwSize);
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}

// Exit if a policy value was found.
if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{   

    if((int)lResult == 1) //  <- problematic place
    {

          ...

     ...
```

I don't know why, but `if((int)lResult == 1)` returns false.

What I need to do to comapare that `lResult  = 0x00000001`.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `lResult` is the success/failure status of the function call, not the actual value of the registry key. The actual value you get is in `dwValue`.

It's very clear if you read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Ouch, I need glasses, thank you, next time I need change the names

Answer (score 1):

your code of

```
if((int)lResult == 1)
```

is inside the if statement:

```
if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
```